# Regex to exclude specific language suffix from url

Tags: regex, pcre

Aim of this question is understand how to exclude only specific language code from url. Lets say we have `example.com/en/test` - this should be a valid match. Other valid urls will be `example.com/ene/test`, `example.com/been/test` and etc. The only url which will be excluded from regex expression is `example.com/en`. I'm definitely not a regex master so all tips will be welcome. I want to modify following expression to exclude only above mentioned url.

```
^(([^/]+/)*[^./]+)$
```

Comment: To be clear, there's no real solution to this problem since an url can have many aspects and can be inserted in a text in many ways. All you can do is a compromise. For example the word `localhost` is itself an url (how to detect that?)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to remove the 2nd and 3rd url from these and get 1st & 2nd:

```
example.com/been/sadvjs
example.com/been/
example.com/been
example.com/en/sghvhj
```

You can try this regex:

```
/([a-zA-z0-9\-]*\/[a-zA-Z]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/g
```

and you can always use `()` to capture.

[Here's](https://regex101.com/r/RZSx9Q/3) a live demo